# Is there a vectorized way to check the values in a DataFrame (e.g. if everything is a string of length 0)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check a dataframe's column and update values if the entire column is just a string of length 0 or NaN.

I know how to access each row and column and iterate through them by each item, but anything I want to perform should be vectorized (or at the very least, as Pythonic as possible)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a dataframe for example purposes, filled with data to be left alone
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['a', 'b'], index=np.random.randint(1,100,10)).sort_index()

# Create an example column that I would modify when encountered in the wild
df['c'] = ''
df['d'] = ''

df.iloc[np.random.randint(low=0,high=(len(df)-1)), df.columns.get_loc('c')] = 'Avoid me'
'''
THIS IS WHERE THE FUN BEGINS :
'''
# If I were to use label-based referencing :

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(row['c']) == 0:
        df.at[index,'c'] = 'Update Me'
        # df.loc[index]['c'] = 'Update Me'

# or if I were to use position-based referencing :

for i in range(len(df)):
    if len(df.loc[i,'c']) == 0:
        df.loc[i,'c'] = 'Update Me'
```

This is the closest I can seem to get to my goal, but I want confirmation that this is the best way to check / update an entire Series at once.

```
if (len(df['c'].unique()) == 1) and (df.['c'].unique()[0]==''):
    df['c'] = 'Update Me'
```

This fills in values in a specified column, but I am looking to avoid a column if there any values besides an empty string (i.e. only alter columns which are only filled with blank strings). Thank you to [Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan) for the input.

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['c'].str.len().eq(0), 'Update Me', df['c'])
```

Comment: You probably want `df['SECTION'] = np.where(df['SECTION'].str.len().eq(0), 'Update Me', df['SECTION']`. Would be easier to answer if you added some example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this one-liner does what you need if you only want to check for empty strings:

```
df.loc[:, (df == '').all()] = 'Update me'
```

If you need the NaNs, just check with them filled:

```
df.loc[:, (df.fillna('') == '').all()] = 'Update me'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set any string that is empty to `'Update me'` you can do as follows:

```
idx_empty_strings = df['SECTION'].str.len() == 0
df.loc[idx_empty_strings, 'SECTION'] = 'Update me'
```

If you want to do it only when the entire column is empty strings *or* `np.NaN` then:

```
col = 'SECTION'
idx_empty_strings = df[col].str.len() == 0
idx_nan = df[col].isna()
if all(idx_empty_string | idx_nan):
    df[col] = 'Update me'
```